# How to force a website to redirect to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect a website to https//.example.com . via Godaddy.
it is a wordpress website I googled it and find this

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^coolexample\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.coolexample\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL
```

I don't whether it works or no could any help me with  what is `SERVER_NAME,REQUEST_URI`, to be added in that code

Comment: I suggest you simply read the documentation. All that is explained in there.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below plugin, its simply move site to https. Once you purchased the ssl.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Answer (score -1):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.